# different request.POST on same page causing DeleteView error Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-channels

My Django 2 app using Django Channels has a `ThreadView` or a page that displays a messaging thread between two users, with URL

```
re_path(r"^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)", chat_views.ThreadView.as_view(), name='thread'),
```

There is a text input form at the bottom of the page to submit a new message via `request.POST` which is handled via the `ThreadView`.

I think the problem is arising when I try to put a `request.POST` delete form (`DeleteView`) on the page as well in order to delete the thread, URL

```
path('<int:pk>/delete/', chat_views.ThreadDeleteView.as_view(), name='thread_delete'),
```

When the delete form is submitted, I get the error

```
DoesNotExist at /messages/2/delete/ User matching query does not exist.
```

With these lines being cited at causing the error (from `views.py` and `models.py`)

```
 self.object = self.get_object() 
 obj, created    = Thread.objects.get_or_new(self.request.user, other_username)
 user2 = Klass.objects.get(username=other_username)
```

The first line comes from the `def post` function on the `ThreadView`, and I'm not sure why that's being triggered.

The thread isn't being deleted as when I go back to inbox, it's still there.

I'm a beginner and may be getting this totally wrong so would appreciate any feedback.

views.py

```
class InboxView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'chat/inbox.html'
    context_object_name = 'threads'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Thread.objects.by_user(self.request.user).exclude(chatmessage__isnull=True).order_by('-timestamp')

class ThreadView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormMixin, DetailView):
    template_name = 'chat/thread.html'
    form_class = ComposeForm
    success_url = '#'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Thread.objects.by_user(self.request.user)

    def get_object(self):
        other_username  = self.kwargs.get("username")
        obj, created    = Thread.objects.get_or_new(self.request.user, other_username)
        if obj == None:
            raise Http404
        return obj

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.get_form()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        thread = self.get_object()
        user = self.request.user
        message = form.cleaned_data.get("message")
        ChatMessage.objects.create(user=user, thread=thread, message=message)
        return super().form_valid(form)

class ThreadDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Thread
    success_url = reverse_lazy('chat:inbox')
```

models.py

```
class ThreadManager(models.Manager):
    def by_user(self, user):
        qlookup = Q(first=user) | Q(second=user)
        qlookup2 = Q(first=user) & Q(second=user)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(qlookup).exclude(qlookup2).distinct()
        return qs

    # method to grab the thread for the 2 users
    def get_or_new(self, user, other_username): # get_or_create
        username = user.username
        if username == other_username:
            print(other_username)
            return None, None
        # looks based off of either username
        qlookup1 = Q(first__username=username) & Q(second__username=other_username)
        qlookup2 = Q(first__username=other_username) & Q(second__username=username)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(qlookup1 | qlookup2).distinct()
        if qs.count() == 1:
            return qs.first(), False
        elif qs.count() > 1:
            return qs.order_by('timestamp').first(), False
        else:
            Klass = user.__class__
            user2 = Klass.objects.get(username=other_username)
            if user != user2:
                obj = self.model(
                        first=user,
                        second=user2
                    )
                obj.save()
                return obj, True
            return None, False

class Thread(models.Model):
    first        = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='chat_thread_first')
    second       = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='chat_thread_second')
    updated      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects      = ThreadManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id}'

    @property
    def room_group_name(self):
        return f'chat_{self.id}'

    def broadcast(self, msg=None):
        if msg is not None:
            broadcast_msg_to_chat(msg, group_name=self.room_group_name, user='admin')
            return True
        return False
```

thread html page

```
 <!-- Delete Thread -->
          <form action="{% url 'chat:thread_delete' thread.id %}" method='POST'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button type='submit' class='btn btn-light' value='delete'>
              <i class="fas fa-trash-alt" style="color:royalblue">
              </i>
            </button>
          </form>

<!-- text input / write message form -->
              <form id='form' method='POST'>
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type='hidden' id='myUsername' value='{{ user.username }}' />
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <center><button type="submit" class='btn btn-success disabled' value="Send">Send</button></center>
              </form>
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'chat'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', chat_views.InboxView.as_view(), name='inbox'),
    re_path(r"^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)", chat_views.ThreadView.as_view(), name='thread'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete/', chat_views.ThreadDeleteView.as_view(), name='thread_delete'),
```

Comment: Show your full URLs. It looks like your request is being served by a different view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Just updated the question

Comment: Note that your `get_or_new` method is assuming a user with `other_username` exists so it will throw an error if a wrong `other_username` is submitted. You should probably gracefully handle that exception .

Comment: In your view's `get_object()` method, set a breakpoint or  `print(other_username)` just to check what's going on. It's strange your ThreadView is being found with this url pattern.

Comment: @dirkgroten If I `print(other_username)` in the `get_object()` I get the username that the logged in user is chatting with, which is correct.  Regarding your first comment, would that be adding an `else` statement? And why would the exception occur if `other_username` is always true?

Comment: other_username is a parameter coming from the url, which could be anything (sure, most users won't tweak it, but anyone can post to your site using any username they want). But ok, that's not really the issue here. The issue is your ThreadView gets the POST instead of the ThreadDeleteView. So my question is, can it be that in your HTML, there's another <form> wrapping the two forms you show here?

Comment: Got it, thanks for the explanation. There is no other <form> wrapping the two forms. Does it have something to do with the URL changing from `username` to `thread.id` or `/messages/bob/` to `/messages/3/delete/`?

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by “changing”. You are absolutely sure the class ThreadDeleteView is defined exactly as you show here, ie only subclassing `DeleteView`?

Comment: Sorry, I mean to say when the delete form is submitted, the page directs to the `thread_delete` URL `/messages/2/delete/` but doesn't seem to be calling the `ThreadDeleteView` and yes it is defined exactly the same as shown here.

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the beginning of your post method and inspect the `request` object. Check the attributes `path` and `resolver_match` to understand how you end up here.

Comment: Would adding a `try except block` be appropriate? Such as `try:
                user2 = Klass.objects.get(username=other_username)
            except Klass.DoesNotExist:
                user2 = None`

Comment: yes it would. But it won't change the matter here: your DeleteView should be called, not your DetailView. The only way to figure out why is to debug step-by-step using a debugger. That's why I asked to set a breakpoint in the post method to look at the request object and to look at the call stack to understand why you get there.

Comment: Yes because once I change that I get `NOT NULL constraint failed: chat_thread.second_id` because the wrong view is still being called for whatever reason